# connect a table to a view

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a view that contains 6.7million lines and now I wanted to add one extra colum from a table that contains the description. However, in that table there are more lines because of different language (9 pcs) description. So that means if I do not put a restriction my 6.7 mill lines will multiple several times if there are more language description for one Item number. If I choose, one language then my 6.7mill view will missing 5%-10% of its content.

I tried the next code.

```sql
where 

language table.[language type]=(
  CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT [Description] FROM [language table] WHERE [language type] = '2') THEN '2'
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT [Description] FROM [language table] WHERE [language type] = '3') THEN '3'
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT [Description] FROM [language table] WHERE [language type] = '1') THEN '1'
    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT [Description] FROM [language table] WHERE [language type] = '4') THEN '4'
END))
```

I expect to use the other language description to fill up this 5-10% missing with the other languages and then if it not found then put a comment there " no description "

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 1):

The next time please try to set up a *stand-alone* sample yourself. This time I did this for you:

```
DECLARE @mockBigTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, SomeValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockBigTable VALUES('Line 1 (just one language)'),('Line 2 (no description)'),('Line 3 (multi language)');

DECLARE @mockDescr TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, ID_bigTable INT, Lang VARCHAR(100), Descr VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockDescr VALUES (1,'en','Descr for 1')
                             ,(3,'en','en-Descr for 3') 
                             ,(3,'de','de-Descr for 3');
```

--Check the output with various combinations.
--Try it with unused languages too (e.g. 'ru')

```
DECLARE @defaultLang VARCHAR(100)='en';
DECLARE @CurrentLang VARCHAR(100)='de';

SELECT bt.*
      ,TheLang.*
FROM @mockBigTable bt
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * 
             FROM @mockDescr d 
             WHERE d.ID_bigTable=bt.ID 
             ORDER BY CASE d.Lang WHEN @CurrentLang THEN 0 
                                  WHEN @defaultLang THEN 1 
                                  ELSE 2 END) TheLang;
```

The idea in short:

`OUTER APPLY` will behave *row-wise*. It will pick the first row returned by the inner `SELECT`. This inner `SELECT` is a *correlated sub-query* due to the `WHERE` clause filtering for the same ID. The magic is the `ORDER BY` in connection with `TOP 1`. If the language equals `@CurrentLang`, it is the prefered value, the `@defaultLang` is the prefered second choice.
If there are descriptions, but non of them is *current* or *default*, a random description will be returned.

Some possible enhancements:

1. add a language table with a *rank* column. This would allow to join your descriptions and order them by the language's rank. You can use `ROW_NUMBER` with a `PARTITION BY` in the `OVER()` clause to find the best response.
2. Use an *inlined TVF* and pass in the language as parameter.
3. Use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of the `OUTER APPLY`, especially if you follow hint 1.